# How do I solve "The Application has unexpectedly quit because it ran out of memory" error in J2ME

Tags: java-me, j2mepolish

I am new to J2ME. I was writing a simple program to request user for their name. I am however getting **The Application has unexpectedly quit because it ran out of memory**.

[image]

How do I solve this?

Comment: Did a stack trace appear on emulator log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by creating a new project and pasting my MIDlets in the new project.